# strip html when using PHP to export mysql to csv

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

I have a php file that I am using to export specific columns from two mysql tables to a csv file. My issue is one of the columns contain html which I need in there when displaying the columns content in a webpage since its content from a wysiwyg textbox. However when I am exporting the column to csv I do not want the html in there. However I am not sure how to strip_tags() so that the column that is written to csv contains no html?

Here is my code

```
<?PHP
   //get database connection
   require("./inc/dbconn.inc.php");

   $surveyid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['surveyid']);

   //get survey name and date to use as the excel file name
     $sname = mysql_query("SELECT survey_name, survey_createdon FROM site_surveys WHERE surveyid='$surveyid' LIMIT 1");
     $snamerow = mysql_fetch_array($sname); 
     $survey_name = stripslashes($snamerow['survey_name']);
     $survey_name = str_replace("'", "", $survey_name);
     $survey_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $survey_name);

     function cleanData(&$str)
     {
         if($str == 't') $str = 'TRUE';
         if($str == 'f') $str = 'FALSE';
         if(preg_match("/^0/", $str) || preg_match("/^\+?\d{8,}$/", $str) || preg_match("/^\d{4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/", $str)) 
           {
         $str = "'$str";
           }
         if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    }


   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$survey_name.csv\"");
   header("Content-Type: text/csv");

   $out = fopen("php://output", 'w');

   $flag = false;
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT survey_comments.the_comment, DATE_FORMAT(survey_comments.commentdate, '%m/%d/%Y %r') AS comment_date, users.fname, users.lname, users.email FROM survey_comments, users 
                     WHERE survey_comments.surveyid = $surveyid AND survey_comments.uid = users.id
                     ORDER BY survey_comments.commentdate desc") or die('Query failed!');
   while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
   if(!$flag) 
{
  // display field/column names as first row
  fputcsv($out, array_keys($row), ',', '"');
  $flag = true;
} 

array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
fputcsv($out, array_values($row), ',', '"');
}

  fclose($out);
  exit;
 ?>
```

Comment: in the loop `$row[field_name_to_strip]=strip_tags($row[field_name_to_strip]);` and you much better to add the field names out side the loop

Comment: Thank you that works. However I have one more issue. The commentdate field in the csv has a '  at the start of each date on each row and I am not sure why? I the commentdate column in the mysql is a date timestamp and has no ' in the actual mysql so I am thinking its something in my code adding a   ' at the start of each date value in the exported csv however not sure how to fix?